# translation for "melee" in Mandarin

Tags: translation

How do you translate "melee" (as in close  hand to hand combat)? I keep getting translations such as "collection of diamonds or diamond fragments", 碎钻.

I've also gotten  "乱斗", but this means attacking in disorderly fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

近战 - close combat
肉搏 - battle of flesh

Comment: looks like 肉搏 is best- at least in a gaming context which I really hope is what OP has in mind.:P

Comment: @MasterSparkles There was a gaming mode in Starcraft 1 called Melee. It was translated to 混战 back then.. I guess it has become a de facto standard in game speak.

Comment: But then I guess it's only for Starcraft..

Comment: @MasterSparkles How did you know I had gaming in mind? :-) (I did)

Comment: http://forum.gamer.com.tw/Co.php?bsn=17407&sn=219 - I'm taking roubo to mean melee in this context. But maybe its a case where usage differs in prc and taiwan?

Answer (score 2):

混战 (hùnzhàn)...........................................

Comment: what dictionary did OP use? iciba has several translations, the first of which is the given one, moreover there are 10 example sentences showing the most suitable choice. OP 用的是什么词典呢？爱词霸词典有几个翻译其中第一个的确是＂混战＂。还有１０个例句让使用者做出最适合的选择。

Comment: I believe 混战 is not melee, it's more like royal rumble

Answer (score 2):

In gaming terminologies in Mainland China, 'melee' is commonly translated into 近战 when it is opposed to 'ranged attack' (远程).

混战 usually means 'free for all'.

Iciba example (http://www.iciba.com/melee/)

> Weapons come in two basic categories: melee and ranged.
>   武器分为两大类: 近战和远程.

Blizzard post on WOW (http://wow.178.com/201308/170793503906.html)

> Range/Melee Inequality
>   近战远程如何平衡